# lftp return code

Tags: shell-script, ksh, sftp, exit-status, lftp

I have written below code to get listing from a remote server.

```sh
echo "set xfer:log yes" > batchfile.txt
echo "set xfer:log-file Templogfile1.txt">> batchfile.txt
echo "open -p $rport -u $ruser,$rpass sftp://$ripaddress">> batchfile.txt
echo "cache flush">> batchfile.txt
echo "cd $rrdir">> batchfile.txt
echo "pwd">> batchfile.txt
echo "ls -l $srfile">> batchfile.txt
echo "quit">> batchfile.txt

exec 3>&1 4>&2                 
exec > TempSessionLog.txt 2>&1 
set -x                         
( 
  lftp -f batchfile.txt >TempLogFile.log <<- EndFTP 
  EndFTP
)  
retval1="$?" 
exec 1>&3 2>&4   
set +x
```

I have passed an incorrect directory name. A standard sftp returns error code `($? != 0)` but lftp sends a success `(retval1 = 0)` return code.

In the `TempSessionLogFile` above, I see the error message `cd: Access failed: No such file (<<Directory Path>>)` with a successful return value.

Is there a way to capture the errors in lftp on the return codes? If not, what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you aren't doing anything subtle with the FTP protocol, which isn't the case here, the easy way is to use normal copying commands, and [mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)) the FTP server to a directory. You can use [LftpFS](http://lftpfs.sourceforge.net/), which is a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem that uses lftp under the hood. Alternatives include [CurlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/). For SFTP rather than FTP, use [SSHFS](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs).

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'fusermount -u mnt; rmdir mnt' EXIT INT TERM HUP
set -e
mkdir mnt
sshpass -p"$rpass" sshfs "$ruser@$ripaddress:/" mnt
cd "mnt/$rrdir"
ls -l "$srfile"
```